# How to calibrate mfp object in R rms package?

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-strategies, calibration

How I can produce following similar calibrate plot (*rms* package) for multivariate fractional polynomial (*mfp* object in R)?

[image]

When I use following function of rms package;

```
calibrate(model_mfp,method="boot",B=1000)
```

It gives an error;

```
Error in calibrate.default(model_mfp, method = "boot", B = 1000) : fit must be from lrm or ols
```

Comment: There is nothing in the `rms` documentation to suggest the MFP is supported.  You would need to contribute new methods to `rms`.  Note that FPs only work in special cases, e.g., where (1) the origin (zero point) of the predictor is "magical" and (2) the predictor cannot be zero or negative.  For these reasons I found more reasons to use regression splines, which are fully supported in `rms`.  FPs are highly sensitive to subtraction of a constant from a predictor.

Comment: Thanks Frank. How to start with calibration of mfp models? Any Idea? Although I knew that mfp is computationally intensive. It took 10 minutes (i5 machine) for 20k observation and 10 predictors.

Comment: You would have to do a lot of digging into the `rms` package `validate.*` and `calibrate.*` functions and especially its `predab.resample` function.  You would also have to write an `rms` wrapper for the main fitting function.  Do you feel that fractional polynomials have an advantage here and are you always analyzing variables that cannot be zero or negative?

Comment: I am trying to build a predictive model. I believe that rcs is better than mfp, but so far I found that standard logistic regression is performing better than mfp and rcs (in my data). Moreover, there is non-linear relationship between response and predictors. I thought that it could be the performance measures (i.e., AUC, Brier Score, HL test, RMSE, R2) are not enough. What could be the reason here? why logistic regression outperforms rcs and mfp?

Comment: You are mixing two ideas: (1) how to relax linearity assumptions on the right hand side of the model and (2) which model to use for the left hand side.  The choice of the left hand side model (and data distribution) has nothing to do with any of this unless I'm missing your point entirely.

Comment: I just want to figure out why logistic regression is performing better than rcs and mfp?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24519/discussion-between-statuser-and-frank-harrell).

Comment: rcs and mfp are not competitors of logistic regression.  You can use rcs and mfp with logistic regression, ordinary (ols) regression, survival analysis, etc.  It sounds as if you are trying to use nonlinear ordinary multiple regression to model a categorical outcome to "bend the probabilities" to make them in [0,1].  If so that is not an appropriate use of the methods.

Comment: I am using logistic regression with and without rcs. I thought that the performance of the model shoud improved with rcs. Isn't it?

Comment: Now I see how you are defining things.  RCS uses logistic regression but you refer to standard l.r.  your findings make sense if the true relationship is linear so that RCS is over fitting.  What fit measure or accuracy score are you using?

Comment: I am using following accuracy measures  area under ROC, Brier Score, HL test, RMSE, R2. Am I missing something? 

One more thing, I found results of rcs are not comparable in glm and rms package. I think implementation of rcs in glm packages is not efficient.

Comment: For the last point I can't comment on that without seeing the code for both the `lrm` call and the `glm` call.  The HL test is not an accuracy score.  I would rely on generalized $R^2$ and Brier score.